# Взаимодействие Lua и JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, html, lua

**Вопрос:** как осуществить выполнения скрипта Lua в приложении java web?

Необходимо по нажатию кнопок осуществить выполнение различных lua скриптов из веб-интерфейса на java, просто даже не знаю где искать и куда смотреть, а задачу выполнить нужно, заранее благодарен.

Comment: Посмотрите на LuaJ: http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую смотреть в сторону [The Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html). Через него можно работать с Groovy скриптами и даже с JavaScript. Если и существует решение для LUA, то это должно быть явно написано с его использованием.